# Resharper - don't mark private methods explicitly as private

Tags: resharper

I want resharper to not put the private access modifier on fields by default - they're already private, I don't need additional modifier.

How do I tell resharper to cut it out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the *Options* of Resharper

In *Code Editing* > *C#* > *Other*

Uncheck *Use explicit private modifier* in *Modifiers section*

**Update (*Resharper 8.1*)**

In *Resharper 8.1*, you can find this options in: *Code Editing* > *C#* > *Formatting Style* > *Other*.
Then Uncheck *Use explicit private modifier* in *Modifiers* section.

**ReSharper 9.1**

ReSharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Code Style -> Modifiers -> Use explicit private modifier (Un-Check)

[image]

Comment: [This option is no longer available in 8.1](http://screencast.com/t/FxnfoMiMoPwR) any idea where it is now?

Comment: Fantastic thanks. Everywhere else I found only the old instructions.